# How To Extend the Controller Class With My Custom Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to get my methods easily from extended controller class and to add some method to the Controller class to use in all other controllers like this:

**Extension**

```
public string GetString()
{
    return "iamanexample";
}
```

**AuthenticationController**

```
public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{
   public IActionResult Index()
   {
       string getMyStr = GetString();
       return View();
   }
}
```

Do I have to create a custom class which inherited by the Controller class and adds my methods in it, and then uses my custom controller class? Or is there any other solution to make it?

Comment: I think this depends largely on personal preferences rather than a standard way. what I do personally is I have a MyControllerBase class, which inherits from Controller, and I have my custom methods there. I then make all my controllers inherit from MyControllerBase instead of the default Controller.

Comment: In this case, I guess, the best solution is to create a BaseController and write all your generic methods in it and let all other controllers inherited from.

You can also create a Helper class that implements all the methods and can be injected throw your class.

Answer (score 5):

You can either go for inheritance or you can create extension method of Controller, I prefer the latter version.

To create an extension method, you can create a static class and create a static method in that class.

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
     public static string GetString(this Controller controller)
     {
          return "iamanexample";
     } 
}
```

Then, you can easily access it through any controller, by writing,

```
string exampleString = this.GetString();
```

Comment: Use extensions when something should always be available. Use inheritance to group a particular set of controller functionality - an `AdminController` for example. Here an extension is the better approach.

Comment: Actually, i want to use this extented methods my all controllers. Is that possible by using extended class situation ? @Riaz Raza

Comment: Yes, you can use this method with any object of Controller class, or a class that's inherited from Controller.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a perfect scenario for inheritance. Create a new controller base class:

```
public abstract class ControllerBase : Controller 
{
    public string GetString()
    {
        return "iamanexample";
    }
}
```

Inherit as:

```
public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase
{}
```